# Jenkins Pipeline ignores exludeMessage Option for git checkout

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins pipeline checks out the GIT repository in the first stage, there fore I'm using

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'MessageExclusion', excludedMessage: '.*\\[Gradle-Release-Plugin\\].*'], [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'master']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '48b64fd8-f0c8-4bcd-91e8-58f763e9be0c', url: 'https://bitbucket.org/private/private.git']]])
```

To prevent builds for automatic version change commit, the excludeMessage options is used. Nevertheless Jenkins starts builds if commits occur with this pattern. The regex pattern is correct, I double checked it. Does somebody facing the same problem?

Comment: May be try using a simpler regex like `.*Gradle-Release-Plugin.*` i.e. no escaping square brackets etc. Is `.*` in the beginning and end required?

Comment: I've tried to use simpler expression, but I seems to be a bug, like stated in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed a bug whose resolution is still pending.

See [issue JENKINS-36195 "Pipeline polling ignores special polling rules"](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195).
The same issue is seen in "[JENKINS-35988 Organization job "Branch Indexing" ignores excluded regions defined in jenkinsfile](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35988)"

The current assessment is:

> Since the git plugin doesn't read the contents of Jenkinsfile when performing polling, I'm not sure how it would honor the polling settings inside the Jenkinsfile in the repository.
>   It seems like it would be even more challenging in a repository with more than one branch, since the polling settings might differ between branches within the same repository.